# If $(X_{i}, \varphi_{ij})$ is a inverse system of nonempty sets and surjective maps, then the inverse limit is nonempty.

Tags: group-theory, profinite-groups

> **Problem.** Prove that if $(X_{i}, \varphi_{ij})$ is a inverse system of nonempty sets and surjective maps indexed by a countable direct set, then the inverse limit is nonempty.

I proved some similar results with different hypothesis combining "*finite*", "*compact*", "*Hausdorff*". I know that if we exclude "*countable direct set*", the statment becomes false. I tried to adapt my others proof for this case, but they didn't work.

My approach in other case was use the discrete topology on $X_{i}$ (then $X_{i}$ becomes Hausdorff) and work with

> If $X_{i}$ are nonempty compact Hausdorff space, then $X$ is nonempty.

But I think that this don't work with this problem, at least, I cannot see.

Bourbaki proof this result with additional hypothesis, but it uses some definitions that are not in Wilson's book. The idea for the proof is show that we can consider $I = \mathbb{N}$ and show that the maps $\varphi_{i}: X \to X_{i}$ are surjective where $(X,\varphi_{i})$ is the inverse limit of $(X_{i},\varphi_{ij})$.

Can someone help me?

Comment: The inverse limit can be realized as a subset of $\prod X_i$ made up of elements that are “consistent” along the $\varphi_{ij}$. You would want to show that such elements exist; you can do so by exhibiting one such element by defining it recursively using the countablitity of the index set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** : $I$ is countable and directed, therefore it has a totally ordered countable cofinal subset, and we may assume it's $\mathbb{N}$.

By categorical abstract nonsense, the inverse limit over $I$ is the same as that of its cofinal subset, that is, over $\mathbb{N}$. Over $\mathbb{N}$ the proof is easy, you build an element of the limit by recursion.

(If you don't like abstract nonsense you can first find an element of the limit over the cofinal subset, and then show how it provides an element of the limit over $I$)

Comment: I got your hint. I'll try this way. Btw, do you know some reference for "*the inverse limit over $I$ is the same as that of its cofinal subset*"? I would like to know a justification.

Comment: I don't know a specific reference, but it's probably done in any document that deals with inverse/direct limits or any document that deals with category theory and has some parts about (co)limits indexed over posets. It's a basic exercise in universal properties

Comment: I'll research. I'm still newbie with inverse limit. Thank you!