# Non-emptyness of projective limit over countable set

Tags: category-theory, order-theory

I am doing exercise 1.9 from [Lenstra's Galois theory for Schemes](http://websites.math.leidenuniv.nl/algebra/GSchemes.pdf).

> Let $\left((S_i)_{i\in I},I,f_{ij}\right)$ be a projective system, where $I$ is countable, all $S_i$ are non-empty and all $f_{ij}$ are surjective.
>
> Prove that $\varprojlim_{i\in I}S_i\neq \varnothing.$

(I will assume he means countably infinite, the finite case being trivial.) Once we can assume without loss of generalisation that $I=\mathbf{N}$, this becomes easy. The crux of the problem, if we don't want to make our hands too dirty, lies in the justification, I think.

Apparently, we can not make this assumption immediately, since a directed countable set is not necessarily totally ordered. Can someone give an example of this?

I know the fact that $\varprojlim_{i\in I}S_i\simeq\varprojlim_{j\in J}S_j$, where $J\subset I$ is a cofinal subset. I saw [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3184495/if-x-i-varphi-ij-is-a-inverse-system-of-nonempty-sets-and-surjective-m/). This seems to prove the following: if $I$ is countable, then there exists a **cofinal totally ordered subset**. He/she proves it in the following way:

If $I$ is countable, there is a bijection $I\simeq \mathbf{N}$, so we can write $I=\{a_n \mid n\in \mathbf{N} \}$. Now define a subset $J=\{x_n \mid n\in\mathbf{N} \}$ of $I$ as follows: $x_0=a_0$, $x_{n+1}=a_{i_n}$, where $i_n:=\min \{j\in \mathbf{N}\mid a_j\geqslant x_n,a_j\geqslant a_n \}$ (this minimum exists because $I$ is directed). This gives $x_{n+1}\geqslant x_n$ and (2) $x_{n+1}\geqslant a_n$, which shows respectively that $J$ is totally ordered and that $J\subset I$ is cofinal.

How does this help? Is there some theorem I don't know of that says that a totally ordered directed countable set is necessarily $\mathbf{N}$? My set theory is pretty rusty apparently. Any help is very much appreciated. :)

Comment: For your first question, you can look at $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$, with product order, i.e. $(m, n) \le (p, q)$ iff $m \le p$ and $n \le q$. For your second question however, note that there are many different order-types for countable ordered sets, try comparing $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{N}$. But note that the map sending $n$ to $x_n$ in this situation is an order-isomorphism between $\mathbb{N}$ and $J$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! If I understand correctly: as $x_{n+1}\geq x_n$ holds for the sequence $(x_n)$, the map $\mathbf{N}\to J,n\mapsto x_n$ is an order preserving bijection, so that we can assume the cofinal subset $J$ is $\mathbf{N}$?

Comment: No problem. What I am saying is that order-wise they are essentially the same thing. So yes, since you only care about order, you can assume that $J$ is $\mathbb{N}$. But in general assuming every countable set to be $\mathbb{N}$ itself might make things more complicated. Since you already have a nice enumeration of $J$ such that it is compatible with it's order, then assuming it to be $\mathbb{N}$ wont change things too much.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my question!

Answer (score 0):

Of course that there are countable directed sets which are not $\Bbb N$. For example $\Bbb{Z,Q}$ and even $\Bbb N$ ordered by $|$ which is not totally ordered, but it is in fact a lattice. The same can be said on the finite subsets of $\Bbb N$ ordered by inclusion.

But nevertheless, if $I$ is a countable directed set, it contains a subset which *is* totally ordered and it is cofinal. This is not necessarily for in general, for example the finite subsets of $\Bbb R$ ordered by inclusion. Any chain must be countable, and its limit must also be countable.

Comment: Clear! The order $\mid$ on $\mathbf{N}$ is not a total order of course. But, why can we say that this totally ordered cofinal subset is wlog $\mathbf{N}$?

Comment: No one is saying that. You're just saying that we start by enumerating the countable set, and going along this enumeration.